# What's with the definition of Environment Marker Variable `python_version` in PEP 508 if the Python version might consist of more than 3 characters?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Just a quick question I stumbled upon. It's not really important, but I'm interested in the reason for this and haven't found a quick answer, yet.

According to [PEP 508 -- Environment Markers (section "Specification" - "Environment markers")](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#id23) marker variable `python_version` is defined as `platform.python_version()[:3]`.

So for Python 3.5.2, `python_version` is going to be `3.5`.

However, what if either major or minor version number is higher than 9? The version number would consist of more than 3 characters and `[:3]` would crop it. Isn't this a possibility for future Python versions?

Why not use something like `".".join(platform.python_version().split(".", 2)[:2])` which still seems very basic and won't overly complicate the code?

Comment: Why care about a rejected PEP?

Comment: I see that PEP 508 states the same derivation from `platform.python_version()`.

Comment: Much better: `'.'.join(platform.python_version_tuple()[:2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been corrected, as a follow-up to this question. See [issue #560](https://github.com/python/peps/issues/560), [pull request #1123](https://github.com/python/peps/pull/1123https://github.com/python/peps/pull/1123) and the [summary of changes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#summary-of-changes-to-pep-508) in the updated PEP:

> - The definition of python_version was changed from `platform.python_version()[:3]` to `'.'.join(platform.python_version_tuple()[:2]`, to accommodate potential future versions of Python with 2-digit major and minor versions (e.g. 3.10). [7]

The `packaging` library source code [has followed suit](https://github.com/pypa/packaging/commit/86a443f3185024edd0b826afdd91d8f9a4917022#diff-99b1c21fa480edb4456d111df29c50ad).

---

*Original answer*

I'm sure it is just an oversight or simplification for documentation purposes. The *intention* is clearly to provide a `major.minor` version string.

Note that historically, there *never has been a minor version number with double digits*. So far, Python has managed with just one digit, always. The highest numbers, so far, have been `1.6`, `2.7` and `3.7`. That's not to say there never will be a `3.10` in future, but so far, it just hasn't come up.

I'd imagine an actual implementation to use [`platform.python_version_tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.python_version_tuple):

```
return '.'.join(platform.python_version_tuple()[:2]
```

or

```
major, minor, patch = platform.python_version_tuple()
return '{}.{}'.format(major, minor)
```

However, both forms are rather a bit more verbose to fit into a PEP table column aiming to document rather than prescribe code.

If in doubt, write to the Python-dev mailing list. I'm sure that if this was to become so confusing as to be problematic, the PEP can be adjusted.

As for pip; it uses the vendored [`packaging` library](https://github.com/pypa/packaging) to handle environment markers, which has [implemented the `python_version` marker verbatim as specced in the PEP](https://github.com/pypa/packaging/blob/c22fbd8c7bfa989df911243b10901645b7d4758d/packaging/markers.py#L267). If you feel strongly about it, you could file an issue there, the PEP maintainers are active on that project.

Note that there is still *plenty* of time. So far, 3.x releases each take about 18 months to appear (3.2: 2011-02, 3.3: 2012-09, 3.4: 2014-03, 3.5: 2015-09, 3.6: 2016-12, 3.7: expected 2018-06), so we have 5 years or so to address this.

Comment: @emmi474: I've linked to the implementation used by `pip`. We have 5 more years before this would become a problem however.